# Reading a HTML file through Groovy Script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

**I need to write a Jenkins pipeline script using Groovy where the below HTML is the input**.

```
<table style="width:30%">
 <TR> 
 <TD>Failed A Count</TD>
 <TD>2869</TD>
 </TR>
 <TR> 
 <TD>Failed B Count</TD>
 <TD>9948</TD>
 </TR>
 <TR> 
 <TD>Failed C Count</TD>
 <TD>3456</TD>
 </TR></table>
```

**I am getting it from a RestAPI, and if any of the value is more than 100 I need to trigger an email.**

```
def response = httpRequest 'REST_API_URI'
println("Status: "+response.status)
def responseBody =  response.content
String[] TDcollection;
String[] splitData = responseBody.split("\n");
for (String eachSplit : splitData) {
  if (eachSplit.contains("Failed")) {
    print(eachSplit);
    }
  }
```

I have tried this, But not able to pick up the value and validate it.

This might seem very easy, but as I am very

new to Groovy, I am kind of stuck on it. Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

No-brainer groovy:

```
String input = '''\
<table style="width:30%">
 <TR>
 <TD>Failed A Count</TD>
 <TD>2869</TD>
 </TR>
 <TR>
 <TD>Failed B Count</TD>
 <TD>9948</TD>
 </TR>
 <TR>
 <TD>Failed B Count</TD>
 <TD>10000</TD>
 </TR>
 <TR>
 <TD>Failed C Count</TD>
 <TD>3456</TD>
 </TR></table>'''

Map<String,Integer> failedValues = [:].withDefault{ 0 }
input.eachMatch( /<TD>Failed (\w+) Count<\/TD>\s*<TD>(\d+)<\/TD>/ ){ _, name, count -> failedValues[ name ] += count.toInteger() }

assert failedValues == [A:2869, B:19948, C:3456]

boolean errorOccured = failedValues.any{ 100 <= it.value }

assert errorOccured
```

Note also the summing up of counts for the same "name".

Comment: Thanks for sharing this.
I am getting below error while implementing it in pipeline script.

org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 3: spread not yet supported for CPS transformation @ line 3, column 30.

 List<Integer> failedValues = ( input =~ /<TD>Failed Value (\d+)<\/TD>/ ).findAll()*.last()*.toInteger()

WorkflowScript: 3: spread not yet supported for CPS transformation @ line 3, column 30.

List<Integer> failedValues = ( input =~ /<TD>Failed Value (\d+)<\/TD>/ ).findAll()*.last()*.toInteger()

Comment: see the update, I replaced spread with `collect{}` call

Comment: Thanks for the update.
But still facing some issue.

  Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods findAll java.lang.Object. Administrators can decide whether to approve or reject this signature.

org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use staticMethod org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods findAll java.lang.Object

Comment: see the update with `eachMatch()`

Comment: Wow, it really worked. If I have to assert a string value , instead of Integer, what should be the process?

The HTML I need to handle is more like :

<table style="width:30%">
 <TR> 
 <TD>Failed A Count</TD>
 <TD>2869</TD>
 </TR>
 <TR> 
 <TD>Failed B Count</TD>
 <TD>9948</TD>
 </TR>
 <TR> 
 <TD>Failed C Count</TD>
 <TD>3456</TD>
 </TR></table>

-------
I am trying the same logic with string , but its not working.

Comment: The int values asserted are dynamic actually. that is what we have to check, if its under 100 or not.